# Increment counter not displayed properly in grafana

Tags: grafana

I have an increment counter and can't display it properly in grafana. First is generated with java `com.timgroup.statsd` and the second one is generated with java `io.micrometer.core.instrument`. Applying the same query does not work.

[image]
First metric:

```
sum(edl_msg_count)
```

Second metric:

```
sum(increase(edl_nt_msg_count_total[$__range]))
```

Comment: Please let me know how to improve the question.